# Web Based GPS Application

Tags: gps

I am doing a project on criminal tracking using gps and i am not allowed to use the goole API as the work must be done solely by the student. I was wondering what kind of map is required to program such application.

I was using a screen shot of a map taken from Google earth and that would be in a bitmap format but i have heard that maps for these application are vector maps that hold information on their coordinates and locations and so on. Can someone brief me on what type of map i would required for an application such as this and how do i go about creating a vector map with stored data if that is necessary for the application.

Or can i use a bitmap image and store its information in a relational database based on x and y coordinated on the screen, i am not sure if that a good approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 widely used formats for GIS applications that you should look into ArcView and MapInfo. There are libraries that simplify the process of reading these formats as well. A GIS file typically stores data in layers. For instance, a street layer would contain a polyline for each street and store additional information such as the name of the street. There are also GIS libraries that help you with such tasks as reverse geocoding, which is the ability to change a GPS coordinate into the closest street name / landmark (something I imagine you might need).

If it's for a sample you can take a photo of an area using Google Earth as you have already done and then store the various features as vectors on your own. A street would become a polyline, for example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok just to clarify what you're saying i can use an application like ArcView or MapInfo to actually develop the map and store information about the map like names of places, longitude and latitude coordinates and so on. Then when i have the map all set up i can then use a library to process the information from the map like retrieve coordinates and perform queries. What i am unclear about is you said i can store the various features as vectors, when u say vectors do you refer to that as the data about the map like the street names and coordinates. Could you just elaborate on that for me please

Comment: If you use the applications mentioned you can either draw the features using their tools or get/buy a ready-made map - you won't have to do anything else. The other approach (the hard way) would be independent of these formats. Let's say you're storing streets as polylines - you store the ends of the street and every turning point's GPS coordinate. The sequence of coordinates makes up the polyline - and that's it, that's the vector. You can store this in a file, in a relational database - anywhere you like and in any format you like.

Comment: I used to store the streets in a table with id, street_name, x_coords (comma-separated x-coordinates), y_coords (same thing), street_length (pre-calculated), max_xy, min_xy. It was an ad hoc approach, but it powered a GPS tracking application flawlessly.

Comment: Ok what i also want to do is get the gps location of a person any where on the map. Does this mean for every x and y coordinate i must store the longitude and latitude location or is there a way to calculate this from the closest gsp location lets a i plot the gsp 
 location for a building. Can you also tell me what libraries there are that i can use to interact with these coordinates. As much information as possible will be greatly appreciated. I would also like to know what books you used when you were developing this application. Thanks a million for you generous help thus far

Comment: I would also like to know if its possible to download the geocode data from Google maps for a particular area. If i can how can i do it.